# Why won't my dropdown ul position change?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-position

I have the ul.children which is the dropdown menu's ul set to

```
position:absolute;
left:-25px;
```

but its position still stays the same as if it were positioned absolutely with left set to 0.  When you hover off of the menu and it fades, it briefly fades 25px left before disappearing.  Do you know what causes this and how I can get it to actually display left:-25px?

reference link: http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/simplybusiness/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in your CSS:

```
div.nav-menu ul li:hover ul,
div.nav-menu ul li.sfHover ul {
left:0;
```

Just remove "left: 0" and it should work! :)